# Android : bitmap is null when getting data from caching using Voley

Tags: android, image, caching, bitmap, android-volley

I am using volley library and displaying image successfully. I want to get same downloaded image from cache . This is my code :

```
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String url){
    String str = "" ;
    Bitmap bitmap = null ;
    byte[] bytes = null ;
    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Entry entry = cache.get(url);
    try {
        str = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
        bytes = str.getBytes("UTF_8") ;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {      
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( bytes, 0,bytes.length,options);
    Log.i(PostItemAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), bitmap+"");
    return bitmap ;
}
```

My issue is that the `bitmap` object is `null` . 
Can any one tell me why ? thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved using the aid of this great [link](https://github.com/rdrobinson3/VolleyImageCacheExample/tree/master/CaptechBuzz/src/com/captechconsulting/captechbuzz/model) where I copied the three files in their `images` package :

- DiskLruImageCache
- ImageCacheManager
- BitmapLruImageCache

Also I copied ***RequestManager*** file. Also there was an issue faced me in the ***DiskLruImageCache*** when creating the key from the URL, and I solved this by replacing few lines in this file.

#### The solution

-old code:
First

```
@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap( String key ) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    DiskLruCache.Snapshot snapshot = null;
    try {

        snapshot = mDiskCache.get( key );
        ....... etc
```

Second

```
@Override
public void putBitmap( String key, Bitmap data ) {

    DiskLruCache.Editor editor = null;
    try {
        editor = mDiskCache.edit( key );
        ......etc
```

-new code:
First

```
@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap( String key ) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    DiskLruCache.Snapshot snapshot = null;
    try {

        snapshot = mDiskCache.get( ImageCacheManager.getInstance().createKey(key) );
       ....etc
```

Second

```
@Override
public void putBitmap( String key, Bitmap data ) {

    DiskLruCache.Editor editor = null;
    try {
        
        editor = mDiskCache.edit( ImageCacheManager.getInstance().createKey(key) );
       .....etc
```

Note : All this modification in ***DiskLruImageCache*** , Beside the caching you can save images to SD Card by this function :

```
    private void saveImageToSD(Bitmap bmp) {
    bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(mCompressFormat, 90, bytes);
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"myImage"+(++i)+".jpg");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*--- create a new FileOutputStream and write bytes to file ---*/
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And calling to this function be inside the ***getBitmap(String URL)*** function witch inside the ***DiskLruImageCache*** file .